# I can't move forward more than one page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm triying to scrape a transfermark web and I can't move fordward more than one page. This is the url of website:
https://www.transfermarkt.es/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/land_id_zu/0/land_id_ab/0/leihe//datum/2022-07-06

my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

urlb = 'https://www.transfermarkt.es/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/land_id_zu/0/land_id_ab/0/leihe//datum/2022-07-06'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(urlb)

# To accept Cookies
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sp_message_iframe_575430"]')))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="notice"]/div[3]/div[2]/button'))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()

while True:
    # button next ">"   
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='A la página siguiente']")))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='A la página siguiente']").click()
```

[image]

With this code I only can enter to sencond page. I'd like can navigate until the final.

Thanks

Comment: are you using next button to go to the next page?

Comment: Maybe try driver.switch_to.default_content() before clicking the next page button as it will reload the page after the first click

Comment: Yes, I was using next button. When my app click on next button the browser keeps thinking. I used     wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, 'value of a count'))).click() but in the page there is a calendar and takes these values first XD. I'd like to know why the next button doesn't work correctly in this case. Thanks both for help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using requests with a custom header instead of Selenium?

The following code works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': '...'}
for x in range(1, 18):
    r = requests.get(f'https://www.transfermarkt.es/transfers/transfertagedetail/statistik/top/land_id_zu/0/land_id_ab/0/leihe//datum/2022-07-06/sort//page/{x}', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    ### find the data you need, save it etc
```

You can find user agents for different browsers easy, for instance here:
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome

Comment: My intention was do this using Selenium to practise, but finally I think this is the option I'll use and I'll investigate why doesn't work well with Selenium. Thanks for you solution.